# how can I migrate the encoded videos from Azure Media Services Account into Indexer?

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I have a huge videos library Azure Media Services with DRM applied using AppLogic, how can I migrate the videos from Azure Account into Azure Video Indexer ?

I have created a new azure-vidoe-indexer resource on Azure, but I don't know what is the next step ?
how can I migrate the videos ? and how can I upload new videos into Indexer ? I used to upload them using AZCopy

Answer (score 0):

Azure Video Indexer supports a variety of input formats, you can use a Azure Blob Storage as an intermediary for the migration.
Use the Azure Media Explorer to extract videos from your Azure Media Services account.
Upload the extracted videos to an Azure Blob Storage account.
Use the Azure Video Indexer API to create a Video Indexer job.

Upload your new videos to Azure Blob Storage. You can use AzCopy.

Create a new Video Indexer job, specifying the source location as the Azure Blob Storage container where you uploaded the new videos.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?terms=Azure%20Video%20Indexer%20

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I already have a BLOB Storage account with videos library already uploaded, how can I connect it the Video Indexer ?

Comment: Sure let me tell you, 

In the Azure portal, create an Azure Video Indexer resource.
Get API Key and Endpoint. After creating the Video Indexer resource, get the API key and endpoint. 
Download and install Azure Storage Explorer if you don't have it installed.
Open Azure Storage Explorer and connect to your Azure Blob Storage account using the account name and key or SAS token.

in the Azure portal, Use the Azure Video Indexer portal to manually upload video files. 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows